# How to remove an item from an observable array which is inside an observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

If there is a ko.observableArray inside a ko.observableArray how would I remove items from it or even select the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you wrap the array with something that makes it easier to recognize. Like:

```
this.boxes = ko.observableArray([
  { id: 1, items: ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3]) },
  { id: 2, items: ko.observableArray([4, 5]) }
]);
```

If you don't want to, it's probably best to either save a reference to the array before wrapping it:

```
const firstBox = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3]);
const secondBox = ko.observableArray([4, 5]);

this.boxes = ko.observableArray([firstBox, secondBox]);
firstBox.remove(2);
```

Note that this removal will *not* trigger an update on `boxes`.

You can also look for an array containing the item you want to remove. Once there are multiple matches, you'll have to decide what to do...

```
this.boxes = ko.observableArray([
  ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3]),
  ko.observableArray([4, 5])
]);

const remove = x => {
  const inBoxes = this.boxes().filter(box => box().includes(x));
  if (inBoxes.length !== 1) // What to do here?
  else inBoxes[0].remove(x);
};

remove(2);
```